# Compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{n dx}{(1+nx)^2(1+x+x^2)}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Compute $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{n dx}{(1+nx)^2(1+x+x^2)}$$

I initially tried to apply theorems that allow me to move the limit under the integral, until I realized that the integral approaches 1 while the function approaches 0 as $n \to \infty$.  Open to any suggestions at this point.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you use partial fractions to evaluate the integral, then take the limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: do the change of variable $y = nx$, so that your integral becomes
$$
\int_0^n \frac{1}{(1+y)^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1+y/n + y^2/n^2}\, dy
= \int_0^\infty f_n(y)\, dy,
$$
with
$$
f_n(y) := \frac{1}{(1+y)^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1+y/n + y^2/n^2}\,
\chi_{[0,n]}(y).
$$
Then use the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Thanks.  Nice solution.